# SharePoint REST API query not returning expected results with $top and $skip

Tags: javascript, html, url, sharepoint

I'm encountering an issue with the SharePoint REST API where my query seems to be returning the same XML response, regardless of the use of the `$top` and `$skip` parameters. Here are the two queries I've been working with:

Query without paging:
http://www.arc.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27test%27

Query with paging:
http://www.arc.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27test%27&$top=20&$skip=10

Despite using $top=20&$skip=10 in the second query, the response appears to be the same as the first query. I was expecting a different set of results, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Additional Details:

I'm using SharePoint to query a list of items.
The list contains more than 20 items that match the query.
I'm testing these queries directly in the browser for simplicity.

What I've Tried:
I've attempted adding a random parameter to the URL to bypass caching.
I've verified that there are more than 20 items matching the query in the SharePoint list.
Any insights into why the paging doesn't seem to be working as expected would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint REST API uses a token for paging rather than the skip and top query options. For more information see, [Page through returned items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#page-through-returned-items).

[image: Page through returned items]